# Logging mouse input for debugging purposes

Tags: debugging, logging, mouse, blender-2.50

I have a persistent issue with a particular UI behavior in Blender 2.56.0. Before anyone tells me that I should be asking about this on the Blender forum, I have...

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117215330/https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=84266#84266)

My question is not what is causing this issue; rather I am searching for tools which may assist me in solving this problem. I suspect what I need is something like a key-logger, but which is able to perform some sort of fine-tuned mouse detection.

Does anyone know any tools (or even workflows) which may be able to assist me in solving this problem?

Comment: Anyone? Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I came across the Visual Studio Coded UI tests today: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_introtocodeduitests.aspx. While this issue is no longer affecting me, I thought people viewing this post may be interested.

Comment: Here is a video for this feature under VS2010 - http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles_Sterling/How-to-create-edit-and-playback-CodedUI-Tests-in-Visual-Studio-2010-Beta2. I was actually looking for the video from the VS2012 start page, but I couldn't seem to find a link. Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd286726(VS.110).aspx